# Accessing private variables in a jQuery callback with the module pattern

Tags: javascript, jquery, closures, revealing-module-pattern

The below executes without errors, but the DOM isn't updated.

```
var Cart = function() {
  var $cart;

  function init() {
    $cart = $("#cart");

    this.refresh();
  }

  function refresh() {
    $.ajax({
      // ...
      success: function(html) {
        $cart.html(html); // $cart seems to exist as JS object, but #cart doesn't get updated in the DOM.
        $("#cart").html(html); // This works!
      }
    });
  }

  return {
    init: init,
    refresh: refresh
  }
}();

$(function() {
  Cart.init();
});
```

**Update**

I wasn't actually calling Cart.init() inside the jQuery ready event contra to what the code above says.

Comment: Did you log the received html to check it ?

Comment: @dystroy: I do, skipped that for brevity. Added dots to be more clear.

Comment: That should work, there's no scope problem here.

Comment: It is working now. I'm trying to understand why doesn't the scope change inside the anonymous function of the success callback?

Comment: @randomguy: The anonymous callback has its own scope, but it also has access to all enclosing scopes (it "closes over" them, see [*Closures are not complicated*](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/02/closures-are-not-complicated.html)). So `$cart` is in scope for everything defined within the anonymous function you're using to create `Cart`.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder: Ah! We don't have problems with $cart because it doesn't get replaced. But "this" does change along with the scope. That's why we need the self/that hack to access the parent scope's "this"! Thanks!

Comment: @randomguy: `this` doesn't change with scope. It changes with function calls, which is different. More: [*Mythical Methods*](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/03/mythical-methods.html) and [*You must remember `this`*](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/04/you-must-remember-this.html). Code in the same function (and thus the same scope) can run with any `this` value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check your `#cart` object exists when you call `Cart.init()`. That's the only difference I see between your two working and not working code as there is no other problem (see [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fsfES/)).

Comment: Problem was that I was calling Cart.init() outside of the ready callback! Thanks, this helped me.

Comment: @randomguy: With this sort of thing, it's always best to quote your **actual** code. In this case, you've shown your call to `init` as being in the `ready` callback, but based on your comment above, it wasn't.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder: Point taken. Will do that in the future.

Comment: And when it's not possible to make the actual code where you had the problem, make a minimal example (for example in jsfiddle as I did) and *test it*.